# No object generated while building MS Casablanca library for c++

Tags: rest, visual-c++, casablanca, cpprest-sdk

Trying to build [Microsoft REST SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn342869.aspx). Got errorious output:

```
1>d:\lb\cpprestsdk\release\include\cpprest\json.h(1386): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
1>d:\lb\cpprestsdk\release\include\cpprest\json.h(1386): warning C4702: unreachable code
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What is wrong there? Why there is no object file generated and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The project is set up to treat warnings as errors. To turn this off, go to the project properties page, *Properties* - *General*, and switch *Treat Warnings as Errors* from *Yes (/WX)* to *No(/WX-)*.

This will allow the binaries to build. A better solution would be to amend the code to remove the warning but I haven't looked at the code long enough to propose a change.